# What should the missing article be?

Tags: indefinite-article

The following paragraph from the classic book, The Adventures of Tom Sawyer by Mark Twain, retold by Doreen de Castro seems to have a missing article in the placeholder (*). Is the missing article "a" or "the"? Would be great if you could tell me why in either case?

> Ben stopped in midbite and watched Tom run the brush daintily over the
>   wood fence, resting against (*) trunk of a tree with legs stretched.

Comment: What do you mean by "retold by Doreen de Castro"? Like a translation or audio book? Unless in the original version, I would say this is a typograpical error.

Comment: I am not sure the author is a native speaker of any English variety. The book is in English, though the publisher is an Indian company. The name of the author was written "Doreen de castro" with **C**astro as **c**atro (lower case) in the first page of the book.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a probable typograpical error or mistake by the author.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I suspect that it is a mistake rather than a typo. This is because mastering articles could prove challenging. However, it just happens this may not be as tricky as in other cases. I thought the missing article was (a) but @nmar believes it is "the". Any ideas?

Comment: @learner Yes, *the*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely missing something, but it's almost certainly the **definite** article *the*. It could be the indefinite article *a*, which would also be grammatically correct, but doesn't sound quite right.

> Ben stopped in midbite and watched Tom run the brush daintily over the wood fence, resting against the trunk of a tree with legs stretched.

Comment: It's **the** trunk of **a** tree, because a tree generally only has one trunk, so that's why **a** trunk of a tree sounds wrong.